# How to make sure interstitial ad is shown in espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, startapp

for ex i wann show startapp interstitial ad in OnResume

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    startAppAd.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}
```

How to test ad shown in espresso

Comment: Its better you can display only one ad onResume

Comment: Hi, I would like to help you, but I don't understand your question. If I know what you mean, you want to run an ad application (not popup or view) inside your app in onResume state, right?